# How to handle RabbitMQ Connection on Node.js to use on Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, jestjs

I have a below code snippet to connect RabbitMQ, Its working fine but in test case, I am getting an *asynchronous operations* error. I tried using `this.start();` and also `this.start().then`

```
var amqplib = require('amqplib');
const { amqp: { uri: amqpURI } } = require('../config');

class Broker {
    constructor(url) {
        this.queue = 'user';
        this.url = url;
        //this.start(); Old
        this.start().then(function (conn) {
            console.log(conn);
        });
    }
    start() {
        return amqplib.connect(this.url).then((conn) => {
            conn.on("close", () => {
                this.conn = null;
                return this.retryConnection();
            });
            return conn;
        }).catch((error) => {
        });
    }

    .....

}
```

*Note : When I comment `this.start();` the error disappear*

**Error :**

> **Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.**
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
>   stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with
>   `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a code to reconnect **RabbitMQ** when connection close. So, When I am closing a connection on **Jest.js** its trying to reconnect RabbitMQ again.

Now, I am reconnecting RabbitMQ only `on close` due to `error`.

```
conn.on("close", (err) => {
    if (err) {
        this.conn = null;
        return this.retryConnection();
    }
});
```